# If $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) = +\infty$, show that $f$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, uniform-continuity

> If $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ and $\lim_\limits{x \to 0^+}f(x) = +\infty$, show that $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

**Edit:** There is a similar question that has been answered, but this one discusses the reasoning behind certain details in more depth.

**Attempt**

Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous. Then $\forall\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t for all $x,y \in S \subset \mathbb{R}$, if $\lvert x-y\rvert < \delta$ then $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert < \epsilon$.

But $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}f(x) = +\infty \implies \lvert f(x) -f(y)\rvert = +\infty > \epsilon$.

**Comment:** I know that this is not formally right due to how I'm using infinity, but I can't figure out how to formalize what I'm trying to say. I understand what is going on with the function and why it can't be uniformly continuous, but expressing it is becoming difficult.

Comment: Use sequential criterion for uniform continuity

Comment: I had thought about that definition, but I'm not given an explicit function so how can I construct an explicit sequence?

Comment: Using the fact that the limit tends to.infinity, this yields $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists x in (0,\inf)$ such that $f(x)>n$(This is not.the definition of the limit, but a weaker statement) then built the succession made by those x

Comment: @Randall I looked at the duplicate, but there wasn't anything informative to me on how to approach the proof.

Comment: @dc3rd  Really?  The answer there by mookid seems very solid and direct to me.

Comment: @Randall perhaps it's because of all your experience you can see it right away, But I don't

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose it *were* uniformly continuous. Pick $\varepsilon > 0$ and the corresponding $\delta > 0$ as in the definition. Choose also an $x$ with $0 < x < \delta$. By uniform continuity, for any $y$ with $0 < y < x$, $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. But then if we take the limit as $y$ approaches $0$ from the right, then $$\lim_{y\to0^+}|f(y)| \le |f(x)| + \lim_{y\to0^+}|f(y) - f(x)| < |f(x)| + \epsilon.$$

This contradicts the fact that $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x) = +\infty$, so $f$ cannot be uniformly continuous.

Comment: How are we able to fix $|f(x)|$? If I am interpreting this correctly, you are taking only the limit as $y \rightarrow 0^{+}$. So we can take the limit of $x$ and $y$ individually? We're allowed to do that?

Comment: no, in the calculation we keep $x$ fixed and let $y$ tend to zero. since $y$ is tending to zero, eventually $0<y<x$

Comment: So as a result of keeping $x$ fixed then $f(x)$ would have to be fixed then...I asked it below to somebody else, but I'll ask here again because the hump I'm having in making a mathematical jump is understanding what I have "license" to play with VS what I cannot.....What thought made you aware to "fix $x$ and then only let $y$ vary? Because my first thinking was that both had to vary all the time together.....perhaps I need to develop a deeper understanding of everything happening.

Comment: to show that something *is* uniformly continuous, you're absolutely right, $x$ and $y$ have to vary. But once you *have* uniform continuity, you don't need the full power of that; you're allowed to use whichever $x$ and $y$ you like as long as they're within $\delta$ of each other. That's why I assumed that we had it, and then tried to find a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ *is* uniformly continuous. Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert<1.$$Now, take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $N>\frac1\delta$. If $x\in\left(0,\frac12\right)$, then there are numbers$$x_0(=x)<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n\left(=\frac12\right)$$with $n\leqslant N$ and $x_k-x_{k-1}<\delta$. But then$$\left\lvert f(x)-f\left(\frac12\right)\right\rvert=\bigl\lvert f(x_0)-f(x_n)\bigr\rvert\leqslant n\leqslant N.$$So, you cannot have $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=+\infty$.

Comment: Two things:  1) What motivated you to take $N > \frac{1}{\delta}$? 2)I'm having trouble understanding your conclusion. So we have the sequence increasing to $\frac{1}{2}$, but what is the chain $|f(x) - f({\frac{1}{2})|$ alluding to?

Comment: 1) Actually, I could have used $\frac1{2\delta}$ instead of $\frac1\delta$ here. The idea was to divide the length of $\left(0,\frac12\right)$ by $\delta$. After this, I can be sure that a can go from any $x\in\left(0,\frac12\right)$ to $\frac12$ in no more than $N$ jumps with length smaller than $\delta$. 2) Note that$$\bigl\lvert f(x_0)-f(x_n)\bigr\rvert\leqslant\lvert f(x_0)-f(x_1)\bigr\rvert+\lvert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\bigr\rvert+\cdots+\lvert f(x_{n-1})-f(x_n)\bigr\rvert$$and that each $\lvert f(x_{k-1})-f(x_k)\bigr\rvert$ is smaller than $1$. So, their sum is smaller than $n(\leqslant N)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume f uniformly continuous on (0,1).

Fix $\epsilon >0$; There exists a $\delta >0$ s,t.

$|x-y| <\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|> \epsilon$ , $x,y \in (0,1)$.

For this $\delta$ there exists a $m$ with $1/m <\delta$ (Archimedean principle).

Set $y=1/m$(fixed).

Choose $n >m$, then $1/m -1/n <\delta$.

Set $x_n=1/n$.

Then

$|x_n-y| <\delta$ implies $|f(x_n)-f(y)| < \epsilon.$

$f(x_n)< \epsilon +f(y)$, i.e $f(x_n)$ is bounded above,

a contradiction since

for $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n =0$ we have$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x_n) =\infty.$

Comment: Why are we able to fix one of either $x$ or $y$? I thought $x$ and $y$ both had to vary....This sort of issue has been coming up a lot for me recently....knowing what I have license to manipulate VS what I cannot.

Comment: I think you forgot the "$" for your latex arguments.